# how to get the size of a dir programatically in linux?

Tags: c, linux, size, dir

I want to get the exact size of a particular dir in linux through a C program.
I tried using statfs(path,struct statfs &) but it doesn't give exact size.
I also tried with stat() but it returns size as 4096 for any dir !

Please suggest me the way through which I can get the exact size of dir just like we get after "du -sh dirPath" command.

Also I dont wanna use du through system().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The disk usage (du) and sum of file sizes (stat) are not the same thing. Which do you want?

Comment: stat on a directory does not return the sum of file sizes. stat on a directory returns the amount of space the directory entry itself uses.

Answer (score 12):

Based on Jim Plank's [example](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Ejplank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/Prsize/src/prsize3.c) to get you started:

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  DIR *d = opendir( "." );

  if( d == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open current working directory\n" );
    return 1;
  }

  struct dirent *de;
  struct stat buf;
  int total_size = 0;

  for( de = readdir( d ); de != NULL; de = readdir( d ) ) {
    int exists = stat( de->d_name, &buf );

    if( exists < 0 ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Cannot read file statistics for %s\n", de->d_name );
    } else {
      total_size += buf.st_size;
    }
  }

  closedir( d );
  printf( "%d\n", total_size );

  return 0;
}
```

Notes, considerations, and questions for the reader:

- This is example is incomplete. See Plank's [notes](http://www.cs.utk.edu/%7Eplank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/Prsize/lecture.html) for more details.
- What happens if there are locked files?
- Do symbolic links need special handling (to avoid infinite loops)?
- How would you output the full path name for erroneous files?

This answer is a starting point, not a complete and robust program to calculate directory sizes. If you need more help, read the source code for the `du` program.

Answer (score 5):

You need to stat() all the files in the current directory and sub directories and add them up.

Consider using a recursive algorithm for this.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the solution may be useful for those who still may encounter the problem.

Here's the function that was written to imitate linux `du` program. It recursively goes through all directories and adds up file sizes.

**Note**, that this function is still incomplete, since it behaves incorrectly on hard links. One should add a container to store file descriptors that point to the same inode entity and use that to get rid of multiple counts of the very same file. `lstat()` is used to handle symlinks (aka soft links), **hard links is an issue here**.

```
size_t countDiskUsage(const char* pathname)
{
  if (pathname == NULL) {
    printf("Erorr: pathname is NULL\n");
  }

  struct stat stats;

  if (lstat(pathname, &stats) == 0) {
    if (S_ISREG(stats.st_mode)){
      return stats.st_size;
    }
  } else {
    perror("lstat\n");
  }

  DIR* dir = opendir(pathname);

  if (dir == NULL) {
    perror("Error");
    return 0;
  }

  struct dirent *dirEntry;
  size_t totalSize = 4096;

  for (dirEntry = readdir(dir); dirEntry != NULL; dirEntry =   readdir(dir)) {
    long pathLength = sizeof(char) * (strlen(pathname) + strlen(dirEntry->d_name) + 2);
    char* name = (char*)malloc(pathLength);
    strcpy(name, pathname);
    strcpy(name + strlen(pathname), "/");
    strcpy(name + strlen(pathname) + 1, dirEntry->d_name);

    if (dirEntry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
      if (strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirEntry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
        totalSize += countDiskUsage(name);
      }
    } else {
      int status = lstat(name, &stats);
      if (status == 0) {
        totalSize += stats.st_size;
      } else {
        perror("lstat\n");
      }
    }
    free(name);
  }

  closedir(dir);

  return totalSize;
}
```

Comment: This looks good simple example.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `'system'`, but are ok to use `'pipe'`,  `'fork'`, `'execlp'` and `'du'`, you could build a pipe, fork a new process, redirect `'STDOUT'` of the child in the pipe, exec `'du'` in the child, and read the result in the parent.  A sample code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  int pfd[2], n;
  char str[1000];

  if (pipe(pfd) < 0) {
    printf("Oups, pipe failed.  Exiting\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  n = fork();

  if (n < 0) {
    printf("Oups, fork failed.  Exiting\n");
    exit(-2);
  } else if (n == 0) {
    close(pfd[0]);

    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[1]);

    execlp("du", "du", "-sh", "/tmp", (char *) 0);
    printf("Oups, execlp failed.  Exiting\n"); /* This will be read by the  parent. */
    exit(-1); /* To avoid problem if execlp fails, especially if in a loop. */
  } else {
    close(pfd[1]);

    n = read(pfd[0], str, 1000); /* Should be done in a loop until read return 0, but I am lazy. */
    str[n] = '\0';

    close(pfd[0]);
    wait(&n); /* To avoid the zombie process. */

    if (n == 0) {
       printf("%s", str);
    } else {
       printf("Oups, du or execlp failed.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: even if using fork  and exec instead of system ,using fork isn't recommended.