# returning value from shell to a C program

Tags: c, awk, linux-disk-free

My question is simple:

I'm writing a program in C with the following structure:

```
int qty_used;

qty_used = system("df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk 'BEGIN{print "Use%"} {percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'");

if (qty_used<fixed_limit)
   /* action 1 */
else
   /* action 2*/;
```

so that if this is the situation:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       2.0T   30G  1.8T   2% /
```

I want qty_used to be loaded with the integer value 2. I never used awk before and I started from this promising answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64815/how-to-print-the-percentage-of-disk-use-from-df-hl. The output of:

```
df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk 'BEGIN{print "Use%"} {percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'
```

sounded good. But if I ask for [I wanted only the integer]:

```
df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk 'BEGIN{percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'
```

then the output is zero and not 2 anymore

Moreover I know that system will not return the percentage I'm searching for but the return status of the command which is useless to my needs

So the question is: is there a quick way to solve this problem starting from these lines?

Thanks to those who will try to help

Comment: Are you sure you're going about this the right way? Unless you need complex data structures, you could just use awk instead of C, and if you do need C aren't there libraries you can include to access UNIX primitives rather than calling shell commands?

Comment: Yes @EdMorton I need C because this part here is a part inside a bigger C program, not just a single request. Referring to the last part of your question I'm not so experienced in UNIX to understand how you would produce a du command answer using UNIX primitives instead of calling the shell commands, for a beginner like me it would be very interesting to know. Thanks for your kind suggestions!

Comment: Ask on usenet at comp.unix.programmer and they should be able to point you in the right direction to use the right prims. This might be a starting point too: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node20.html (I just googled "UNIX file stats from C program"). You might also find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129499/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-dir-programatically-in-linux interesting.

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as possible... you are very kind, thanks for finding me the right references and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that the `system()` function returns a value related to the *exit code* of the command, not anything related to the output of the command.  You also need to understand that the range of possible exit codes is pretty small.

With that said, if you only need to support integer values between 0 and 100, then you should be able to make the command exit with the appropriate code.  This should do it:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* ... */

    qty_used = WEXITSTATUS(
            system("exit `df -h | awk '/sda1/{percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'`"));
```

**Update**: removed the `grep` from the command pipeline, per @EdMorton's comment.

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk: `df -h | awk '/sda1/{percent+=$5} END{print percent}'`.

Comment: thanks @john, this is just the answer I was asking for! with respect to the system() function my words were a quote from "return value" paragraph in http://linux.die.net/man/3/system where they mention also your suggested WEXITSTATUS. Thanks again for the great support!

Comment: @Antonino, I'm pleased to be of service. Do note, however, that although `WEXITSTATUS()` is needed, it's not the secret sauce.  The key is to convert the pipeline output to an exit code by making it an argument to the shell's `exit` command.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way...

have the last function (awk) redirect the output to a file (using '> filename')

then open the file for reading and extract the desired information.

Comment: thank you @user3629249, I read about this approach in other answers but if possible [= if there is another quicker way to solve it starting from my draft] I would prefer not to open and work on a file for just a single number. Anyway your help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This increments percent in the BEGIN block...

```
$ df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk 'BEGIN{percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'
0
```

Please compare (perhaps this is what was intended?)

```
$ df -h | grep 'sda1' | awk 'BEGIN{percent=0;} {percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'
2
```

Also, system returns the status of the command, not its output.
Please consider using popen and reading from the stream.

As an example using popen...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 2048

int get_percent_used (const char* devicename);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int qty_used = get_percent_used("/dev/sda1");
    printf ("qty_used = %d percent\n", qty_used);
    return 0;
}

int get_percent_used (const char* devicename)
{
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char command[SIZE];
    FILE* pipe = 0;
    int percent = 0;

    sprintf (command, "df -h | grep '%s' | awk 'BEGIN{percent=0;} {percent+=$5;} END{print percent}'", devicename);

    if (!(pipe = popen(command, "r"))) {
        perror("open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, SIZE, pipe) != NULL) {
        percent += (int) strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
    }
    pclose(pipe);

    return percent;
}
```

Comment: thanks @codess, as I said before I read about system() function in the link given in the other comment... your second line is just what I was trying to do... then I wanted that value [i.e. 2] to be loaded in a C integer as John did... thanks to you too for your support!

Comment: Thanks @Antonino.  WEXITSTATUS still only returns information about process exit status as far as I can tell; so I edited my answer to add a code example anyway, in case it helps at all.

Comment: thanks again! it will help for sure, me and who will read for the same problem